# Compare two columns (A and B) in spreadsheet 1 against two columns (C and D) in spreadsheet 2, if A=C and B=D, then extract values

Tags: excel-formula

Compare values in three columns (A, B and C) in Book1 against three columns (A, B, C) in spreadsheet 2. When the combination A, B, C on book1 is found in book2, then populate column D in book1 with the values in column D of book2.  Attaching screenshot of a sample data.[Screenshot]

Comment: Is this a homework question? Could you explain what you've already tried. Perhaps attach some visual aid

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's only one match, the following should work. This example would apply for row 5 of column F of Spreadsheet 1.

```
=sumifs(E1:E1000,C1:C1000,A5,D1:D1000,B5)
```

Comment: I tried the below but no luck:Use Index & Match, in column C of the First sheet. You will need to hit Ctrl+Shift+Enter after you enter this in the formula bar so that excel knows it's an array formula:
=INDEX(Sheet2!C:C,MATCH(1,(A1=Sheet2!A:A)*(B1=Sheet2!B:B),0))